# Adding an HTML form into a page in Kooboo

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, kooboo

I have Kooboo CMS. I want to add an HTML input form for submitting data. How do I add any HTML form to a Kooboo page?

Answer (score 3):

I think it's easy. I think you need to:

1. create "Content type" for your form (like this
   -http://wiki.kooboo.com/?wiki=Content_type_management)
2. create "Content folder" for this content type
   (http://wiki.kooboo.com/?wiki=Folder_management)
3. create view and use code helper "Form" - "Add content" - you'll get
   a html form template for add content, you need just to write a
   content folder and fields from content type.

More about KooBoo CMS [here](http://kooboo.com/) and [here](http://kooboo-cms.ru/)